# When does convergence of joint distributions imply convergence of marginal distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

There is much discussion of conditions under which convergence of marginal distributions implies convergence of joint distributions.  But I can find no discussion of the converse. Can someone point to a proof or counterexample?

Comment: Are you talking about convergence in distribution, $(X_n,Y_n)\overset{d}{\to}(X,Y)$?

Comment: Yes.  And for simplicity, suppose all variables take values in the positive integers.

Comment: I think you can conclude $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ by continuous mapping (you don't need integer-valuedness for that)

Comment: Sorry.  Don't know what you have in mind.

Comment: If $(X_n,Y_n) \overset{d}{\to} (X,Y)$, then applying the Continuous mapping theorem to the continuous function $(x,y) \mapsto x$ yields $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$.

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you mean.  I'll have to think more about whether or not I really want convergence in distribution or some other form.

Comment: @hgmath I'm facing the same issue atm. Could you perhaps elaborate on how to apply the CMT to the continuous function?